# Javadoc for JPMS modules when module name is different from artifactId

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, java-module, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a sample [project](https://github.com/PashaTurok/jpms-javadoc-test1) with two jpms modules. It is a maven project with one parent and two child modules.

A parent pom:

```
...
<modules>
    <module>foo.api</module>
    <module>foo.impl</module>
</modules>
...
```

API module pom:

```
...
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>foo.api</artifactId>
...
```

API module-info:

```
module com.foo.api {
    requires org.slf4j;
    exports com.foo.api;
}
```

These are my settings for maven-javadoc-plugin (in parent pom):

```
   <reporting>
         <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <reportSets>
                  <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                      <report>javadoc-no-fork</report>
                      <report>test-javadoc-no-fork</report>
                    </reports>
                  </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
                <configuration>
                    <doclint>none</doclint>
                    <dependencySourceIncludes>
                       <dependencySourceInclude>com.foo:${project.artifactId}</dependencySourceInclude>
                    </dependencySourceIncludes>
                    <doctitle>Title - ${project.version}</doctitle>
                    <includeDependencySources>false</includeDependencySources>
                    <windowtitle>Title</windowtitle>
                    <additionalJOptions>
                        <additionalJOption>--no-module-directories</additionalJOption>
                    </additionalJOptions>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

And when I run `mvn javadoc:javadoc` I get:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0:javadoc (default-cli) on project foo.api: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: 
Exit code: 1 - error: module not found: com.foo.api
```

Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: *module not found: `com.foo.api`* is for the maven module, right? some typo there or am I missing to find this module in the shared configuration?

Comment: @Naman no, this is not type. In my situation the name of the module in module-info != maven module name. That is the problem.

Comment: I reproduced your issue with the sample repo, but I think you could do to trim it down more. Keep trimming until you can't reproduce your issue anymore, and that will be a clue. Can you do it with a single module? Can you remove all the extra dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In case of modules, javadoc requires a compiles module descriptor, so it is necessary to do `mvn compile javadoc:javadoc` instead of `mvn javadoc:javadoc`